# How to create a loop when comparing to columns

Tags: vba, excel, messagebox

I want a validation that if column AP is greater than column X display a message, however I would like this message to only appear once and once only ever. For example if cell ap7 is greater than x7 than display a message, then user clicks ok. Then if cell ap8 is less than x8, I don't want the message from the previous validation to appear again.

```
Dim lstrw As Long
Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Main")
        lstrw = .Range("AP" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lstrw
            If .Cells(i, "AP").value > .Cells(i, "X").value Then
                MsgBox "Your Pieces Are Over Suggested", vbOKOnly
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: you will need to loop, you cannot compare a full column to anther full column at once.

Comment: @ScottCraner any suggestions in how to do that?

Comment: The answer from scott is great, however I just now realized that I would prefer it display only once for that row is that something that's possible.

Comment: What do you mean once for that row? Once ever? What if the value is changed in that row in either Column X or Column AP? Should that reset the validation for the row? I think in the case of this question, more information is better than less information to help us offer an optimized solution. Having Excel loop over an entire column of data everytime the worksheet calculates can slow things down tremendously.

Comment: @user3561813 please see rephrased question

Comment: If you're no longer validating using the `Calculate` event, then you'd need to determine when to validate. Are users entering data into these cells, and do you want to validate upon user input, or is this information some type of data import? Does the data in either of the columns in question change?

Comment: @user3561813 No the values derive from formulas, and validate upon the users input. And yes it may change but Once it's validated I don't want it to validate again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim lstrw As Long
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Main")
    lstrw = .Range("AP" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lstrw
        If .Cells(i, "AP").Value > .Cells(i, "X").Value Then
            MsgBox "Your Pieces Are Over Suggested", vbOKOnly
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End with 
End Sub
```

Comment: Let's hope for several volatile functions in that workbook.

Comment: it worked fine, but then started to get a debug on If .Cells(i, "AP").value > .Cells(i, "X").value Then

Comment: @ScottCraner works great! This might be more in depth, but would you know how to only validate this statement once? For example once the message pops up the user clicks ok, then don't repeat that message for that row

Comment: @findwindow  -Yes, Worksheet_Calculate would not be my first choice to put validation code. Depending on the complexity of the worksheet, that is going to run a lot of times it doesn't have to.

Comment: @Jeeped any suggestions of a better event to run for validation?

Comment: @Luis data validation?

Comment: @Luis is the data in both columns calculated or are they entered by the user one for one?

Comment: @ScottCraner they are both formula calculated column "AP" from other sheets and Column "X" from within the "Main Sheet"

Comment: @Luis your best bet is to get rid of the formula and do a worksheet_change event on the data entry that does the check and inserts the correct value in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily without VBA. In a third column (I'll use Z), copy and paste the following formula down the column, replacing 1 with the index of your first row:

```
=AP1>X1
```

Then in a nearby cell, do

```
=COUNTIF($Z$1:$Z$N, FALSE)
```

where N is the index of your last row. You can then check whether that cell's value is greater than 0.

Comment: this works to some extent but not exactly what I asked, this won't display a pop up message and also I want this to be a triggered event not already calculated

Comment: You could always check within your program that the value is greater than 0 and throw a msgbox if it is. I understand only needing the value at a certain point in the code, but you can ensure get the correct value at any given time with a refresh.